# firebase snapshot will not return value

Tags: database, angularjs, firebase

Another Question here,

I am using firebase and angular js, and  trying to return data from my database to the console log using this code :

```
        function userCtrl($scope){
    $scope.userName="";
    $scope.myData = new Firebase ("https://yjyc-signup.firebaseio.com/Entries");
    $scope.users={};

        $scope.saveUser = function(){
          $scope.myData.push({userName: $scope.userName});
            $scope.userName="RESET";
        };
   $scope.myData.on('value', function(snapshot) {
       $scope.users = snapshot.val();
       console.log("Author: " + $scope.users.name);

});
```

but the console return "Author: Undefined" although I have a value in my database of a name.

is anybody can help me that would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

When using AngularFire you need to sync the reference before you can get any data from it. Also you're trying to use a Firebase function that doesn't exist for AngularFire as far as I'm aware. Instead try to register a `$watch` function in your controller and each time that `$watch` executes you grab the information from the reference. Something like this:

```
myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('watchedExpression', function() {

        var ref = new Firebase ("https://yjyc-signup.firebaseio.com/Entries");
        var syncedRef = $firebase(ref);

        console.log('Author:' + syncedRef.name); //You need to change this path to work with your Firebase tree structure

    });

}]);
```

If you don't want to register a `$watch` function you can look at the threeway data-binding, you can look at this [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-bindtoscope-varname) in the AngularFire documentation.

Comment: OP seems to not be using AngularFire, just the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK with AngularJS,

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is that even possible?

Comment: Yup. Since AngularFire is just a glue-layer between the Firebase JavaScript SDK and AngularJS, you can also bypass it and glue the SDK and AngularJS together yourself. Over time you'll probably end up building something akin to AngularFire, but it will definitely ben an educational experience. :-)